# Is it a good idea to fill a std::vector<char*> with elements created with new operator?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, char

I have a `std::vector<char*> list;`
I have strings I want to add there at runtime that is stored in `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> splitted;`

```
std::vector<char*> list; //my list

for (int i = 0; i < splitted.size(); i++)
/* splitted is a vector, that is holding another
 * vector<unsigned char> */
{
    /* Allocate new memory... is this really needed? Because
     * if I use static var, then every list element will be
     * the same as that var. */
    char *temp_name = new char[splitted[i].size() + 1]; 

    //copy bytes from source to new var
    memcpy(temp_name, &splitted[i][0],
           sizeof(unsigned char) * splitted[i].size());
    temp_name[splitted[i].size()] = 0; //add zero byte
    list.push_back(temp_name); //push in vector
}
```

I ask because I am not sure if there is no memory leak will occur when `list` will be out of scope.
Maybe there is some better way to fill such vectors.

Comment: Just use a vector of `std::string`.

Comment: _'Is it a good idea to fill std::vector<char*> elements with elements created with new operator?'_ Certainly not! :P ...

Comment: @chris `std::unique_ptr<char*>` is not bad either... depending on use-case. Might even be far more efficient.

Comment: @Deduplicator, Sure, but chances are a string is ok. I guess having both choices available could be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like chris said in the comments, just use a `std::string`. It's (1) shorter code and (2) safer.

```
std::vector<std::string> list;

for(const auto & vec : splitted){
    list.emplace_back(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Or if your C++ implementation doesn't have `emplace_back` support or range-based for loops (I'm looking at you, VS2010), then do something like

```
std::vector<std::string> list;

for(int i = 0; i < splitted.size(); i++){
    list.push_back(std::string(splitted[i].begin(), splitted[i].end()));
}
```

Comment: code do not compile in VS2010 express. I remake it to:  `std::vector<std::string> list;

 for (int i = 0; i < splitted.size(); i++)
  list.push_back((char*)&splitted[i][0]);`

Comment: @Kosmos Don't do that unless the last character stored in the vectors in `splitted` is guaranteed to be `'\0'`.